# how can a bruteforce occur on a pbkdf2?

Tags: bcrypt, brute-force, pbkdf2, scrypt

am sorry for this question, but i was asking: when using MD5, we get a hash, so to get the password we hash all the words untill we find the same hash.

but in a key derivation algorithme such pbkdf2 or bcrypt or scrypt, what a hacker need to seek? or he will make the same algorithme to all words to get the same key derivation?

am sorry for this dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s the same general idea - try all the hashes - but several thousand (or million, or even billion) times slower.

Comment: so he uses the same algorithme?

Comment: @AbdelouahabPp: No, they’re all different hashing algorithms.

Comment: but the brutefore is the same?

Comment: ah ok, thank you, because i thought that even the bruteforce must make an intermediate operation, i was dumb ^_^